# Static Factories Methods

Tags: java

One advantage of static factories method states that:

**Unlike constructors they can return an object of any subtype of their return type which gives you great flexibility in choosing the class of returned object.**

What does this mean exactly?
Can someone explain this with code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        // If this is called by someone saying "new Foo()", I must be a Foo.
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {
        // If this is called by someone saying "new Bar()", I must be a Bar.
    }
}

public class FooFactory {
    public static Foo buildAFoo() {
        // This method can return either a Foo, a Bar,
        // or anything else that extends Foo.
    }
}
```

Comment: Here what's the advantage of having a single factory method return objects of parents and subclasses.If I wanted for a parent type object variable to hold an object of the subclass type I can have a constructor of the subclass generate it what's the harm in that.I am not getting how this would be a useful thing to do.

Comment: @david.colais This link has a long list with explanations of the various benefits: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec1

Answer (score 1):

Let me break your question in two parts
*(1)* Unlike constructors they can return an object of any subtype of their return type 
*(2)* which gives you great flexibility in choosing the class of returned object.
Let say You have two classes Extended from `Player` which are `PlayerWithBall` and `PlayerWithoutBall`

```
public class Player{
  public Player(boolean withOrWithout){
    //...
  }
}

//...

// What exactly does this mean?
Player player = new Player(true);
// You should look the documentation to be sure.
// Even if you remember that the boolean has something to do with a Ball
// you might not remember whether it specified withBall or withoutBall.

to

public class PlayerFactory{
  public static Player createWithBall(){
    //...
  }

  public static Player createWithoutBall(){
    //...
  }
}

// ...

//Now its on your desire , what you want :)
Foo foo = Foo.createWithBall(); //or createWithoutBall();
```

*Here you get the both answers* **Flexability** and *unlike constructor behaviour*
Now You can see **through these factory methods its upto you that WHICH TYPE OF PLAYER YOU NEED**